# Finding specific key in a large nested dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have multiple python dictionaries in this format, where the top-level keys "3224987", "3590845" etc are not constant they vary per dictionary.

```
dict1 = {
            "3224987": {
                "data": {
                    "skyscrapers":[]
                }
            },
            "3590845":{
                "data":{
                    "bungalows": {
                        "loc": "leo"
                    }
                }
            },
            ...
            "3405901":{
                "data":{
                    "studio":{
                        "rooms": {}
                    }
                }
            }
        }

dict2 = {
            ...,
            "784939":{
                "data":{
                    "studio":{
                        "rooms":{}
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

I am interested in the items within the **"studio"** key, in the above dictionary i can locate them with `dict1["3405901"]["data"]["studio"]` but in other dictionaries it can have a different top level key like  `dict2["784939"]["data"]["stuido]`.
How can I do this iteratively across many dictionaries (dictX) without worrying about the top-level key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have many keys and are not sure if they contain "data" and "studio" you could use try/except:

```
dict_list = [dict1, dict2...]

for dic in dict_list:
    for key in dic:
        try:
            studio = dic[key]["data"]["studio"]
            # do your stuff with studio
        except KeyError:
            continue
```